# How to programmatically configure a widget in blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I'd like to create a functionality to distribute a blogger widget similar to what LinkWithin offers.
My user register to my service providing their blog name and I'd like to redirect them to their blogger console, in the add widget page.

The problem is that I don't know where to start :|

any pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question to be usefull to other people :)

liky: http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=53219